# Metric geometry

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$ and $B$ be points in a metric geometry. Show that there is a point $C$ such that $C\in \vec{AB}$ and $d(A,C)=d(C,B)$.

How can I prove this?

Definitions:

**Ruler**: Let $l$ be a line in an incidence geometry. Assume that there is a distance function $d$. A function $f: l \to \mathbb{R}$ is a ruler for $l$ if $f$ is a bijection and for each pair of points $P$ and $Q$ on $l$ we have $|f(P) - f(Q)| = d(P,Q)$. Where $f(P)$ is called the coordinate of $P$ with respect to $f$.

**Metric geometry**: An incidence geometry $\{P, L\}$, where $P$ is the set of points, $L$ set of lines, together with a distance function $d$ satisfies if ever line $l\in L$ has a ruler.

**Line**: If $\{P,L\}$ is an incidence geometry and $a,b\in P$, then the unique line $l$ on which both $a,b$ lie will be written as $l=\vec{ab}.$

Comment: What is a ruler? And what exactly does the distance function $d$ have to satisfy?

Comment: @Braindead I have made the edit to include the definition of a ruler. And do you mean what specific distance function we are using?

Comment: The sentence defining metric geometry doesn't make sense to me. What is the definition of a distance function?

Comment: @Braindead The distance function definition is the same here on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29). And also the definition of incidence geometry is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_geometry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: Use the bijection given to you by the Ruler axiom. If you have two points on $\mathbb{R}$, you can find their midpoint.

You should be able to write a formula for $C$ in terms of $A, B$ and your bijection.

I can give you more details if necessary, but see if you can use my hint.

---

Let $l$ be the unique line through $A$ and $B$.

The Ruler axiom tells us that there is a bijection from $l$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let's call this bijection $g$.

Then, $g(A)$ and $g(B)$ are points on $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $g(A)$ and $g(B)$ are both numbers.

How do you find the midpoint between two points on the real number line? That is, given two numbers, how can you find the number that is exactly halfway between them?

---

$g(A)$ and $g(B)$ are point on the real number line, i.e., they are numbers. Therefore, it makes perfect sense to take their average:

$$\dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}$$

This point, $\dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}$ is exactly halfway between $g(A)$ and $g(B)$.

Note that without the $g$, i.e. the operation $\dfrac{A + B}{2}$ doesn't make any sense because $A$ and $B$ aren't numbers. Addition $A+B$ doesn't make sense (it is not defined).

Now,, $g(A), \dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}, g(B)$ are all points on the real number line $\mathbb{R}$. We are still a bit away from finding out midpoint $C$.

How can we get back to the metric geometry? How can we get back a point on our line $\vec{AB}$?

Hint: How did we end up on the number line in the first place?

---

You are almost there.

You have concluded that our point $C$ must satisfy the equation

$$g(C) = \dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}.$$

Is it possible to solve for $C$ in the equation above?

Hint: What kind of map is $g$?

It might be helpful to think of solving for $C$ when you have

$$g(C) = X$$

(where $X$ of course, stands for $\dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}$)

---

Since $g$ is a bijection, it has an inverse, $g^{-1}$.

$$C = g^{-1}\left(\dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}\right)$$

It remains to show that $d(A,C) = d(B,C)$, but this should be a straight forward computation, using the ruler axiom.

To start off,

$$d(A,C) = |g(A) - g(C)|$$

$$d(B,C) = |g(B) - g(C)|$$

Try to fill in the rest of the details.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer.

Comment: To find the number that is exactly halfway between them then I will just divide it by $2$.

Comment: @Alex Exactly what are you dividing by 2? Let's say you have numbers $5$ and $9$. What do you need to divide by $2$ to get the number that is halfway between $5$ and $9$? In general, what do you need to divide by $2$ to get something that is halfway between two numbers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In order to do that I will have add $a$ and $b$ and divide by $2$. Thus, $a+b/2 = M$, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. So if you want to find the midpoint of real numbers $g(A)$ and $g(B)$, you would have to add those two and then divide by 2. (Note: You should have $(a+b)/2$ rather than $a+b/2$.)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! How can I show this formally that this point does in fact exist? And would my distance function be $d(A,C)$ where $A$ is a point and $C = (a+b)/2$?

Comment: Not quite. You can't add the points $A$ and $B$. $A$ and $B$ belong to the metric geometry, and they aren't numbers! See my edited answer.

Comment: "How can we get back to the metric geometry" hmm, I am not sure how? We must find a ruler for our line $\vec{AB}$?

Comment: @Alex Throughout my answer, I am using the Ruler axiom. I called the bijection $g : \vec{AB} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So far what I understand is that, let $l$ be our line where $A,B \in l$. So there is a bijection $g: l \to \mathbb{R}$ which must satisfy $|f(A) - f(B)| = d(A,B)$. We can then find the midpoint by dividing our line by $2$ hence $g(C)=\dfrac{g(A) + g(B)}{2}$ so $|f(A) - f(C)| = d(A,C)$ must equal $|f(C) - f(B)| = d(C,B)$.

Comment: Switch the $f$ with $g$. Now, why does $C$ exist? (Can you write an expression for $C$? Like $C = something$?)

Comment: $C$ is a point. I can understand intuitively why it exists since a line in a metric geometry has infinitely many points but I don't know how to formally show it. If I let $A = (a_1,b_1)$ and $B = (a_2,b_2)$ then I can let $C = ((a_1+a_2)/2,(b_1+b_2)/2)$

Comment: I made an edit in the answer above. I'll check back during the day tomorrow, but try to see if you can take our discussion together into a coherent solution.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: So, since $A$ and $B$ are points in a metric geometry and $g$ is a bijection we can conclude that there is a point $C\in l$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alex Right. So you start with $A$ and $B$. There is a bijection $g: l \to \mathbb{R}$. $g(A)$ and $g(B)$ are numbers. You can take their average. $(g(A) + g(B))/2$. This is a number. $g$ is a bijection, so use the inverse $g^{-1}$ on it to get a point $C$ in $l$. It remains to show that $d(A,C) = d(B,C)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!